# white border around background images?

Tags: android

I am editing sipdroid http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/ and jsut want to change the background to be custom images. By default they are a grey color and teh whole screen is grey, however when i add in the background imagines they have a white border around them, why is this? How can I change it, in styles.xml or somewhere?

[image]

bottom is the image name, before i added bototm in tow places the lines read:
`android:background="#736f6e"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    **android:background="@drawable/bottom">
<!--android:background="#736f6e"-->**
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:paddingRight="15dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dip">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:shadowDx="1"
                    android:shadowDy="1"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:shadowColor="#aaaaaa"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"/>

                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/contacts_button"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_dial_pad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.InstantAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_callee2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint2"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.InstantAutoCompleteTextView>

            <org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.InstantAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_callee"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        **android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!-- android:background="#736f6e" -->**


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/create_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/menu_create" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the margin isn't part of your image? the layout is set to  fill parent, it may just have that small padding around it (just thought i'd check)

Comment: weird, you are correct, gimp does not show the white border but i open in image viewer and can see it.

Comment: As a suggestion that probably won't help your issue here, you should really look into how to use RelativeLayouts. Your nesting of views is pretty deep and unnecessary which results in degraded performance and hard to read XML.

Comment: yeah I think the xml is pretty bad here, I didnt write it, this is an app from the market.

Comment: @Paul - Ah ok.. Well I was bored so I fixed it http://pastebin.com/CF0SwZaL Obviously some of the paddings and little spacing tweaks will need to be re-added and I changed the auto complete texts to EditTexts just so I could view them.

Comment: Cool thanks, will replace the code with this, theirs is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

As a long term solution Dymmeh is correct. You should look into RelativeLayouts.

For this question, depending on what your exporting your image out of GIMP as and the size of your image relative to the layer content, it will add a small white margin.

Try making sure all of your layers are equal to the max size of the image and exporting as PNG plain. Check all of the options.